# Is there any way to integrate Mylyn with Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket, mylyn

Bitbucket has an issue tracker, can it be turned into Mylyn tasks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is what I found  https://bitbucket.org/shuji.w6e/bitbucket-mylyn-connector/
Haven't used it personally though.

Comment: It didn't work the way I expected. I had to submit a bug report https://bitbucket.org/shuji.w6e/bitbucket-mylyn-connector/issue/2/cant-submit-task

Comment: The update site for it is http://updates.deathmarch.jp/ documented at https://bitbucket.org/shuji.w6e/bitbucket-mylyn-connector/wiki/Home . Eclipse4.10.0.I20181206-0815 on jdk1.8.0_192 reports: `java.net.UnknownHostException: updates.deathmarch.jp: Temporary failure in name resolution`. `nslookup` reports: `can't find updates.deathmarch.jp: SERVFAIL`. Google Chrome reports: `ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED`.

Comment: When I disabled IPv6 at OS settings, I had `java.net.UnknownHostException: updates.deathmarch.jp`

Answer (score 43):

FYI - here is a fork of that original mylyn connector project that is active. I installed it using the wiki notes today and it seems to work without a problem.

https://bitbucket.org/pplupo/bitbucket-mylyn-connector/wiki/Home

Comment: The latest, installed today from http://babelserver.org/mylyn-bitbucket/, works for me on Eclipse Mars.

Comment: Did not work with Eclipse 4.10: «Could not find http://babelserver.org/mylyn-bitbucket/ ». Same error with Eclipse 4.5.2 aka Mars.2.

Comment: Same error with Ecl.Photon Release. Reported at https://bitbucket.org/pplupo/bitbucket-mylyn-connector/issues/72/could-not-find-babelserverorg-mylyn

Comment: http://babelserver.org/mylyn-bitbucket/ url was fixed by the maintainer. Works on Eclipse Photon 4.8.0 Release

Comment: babelserver.org/mylyn-bitbucket responds with a 404